# Recommend tag merger: judge - judiciary

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I recommend a merger of [judge](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judge) and [judiciary](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary). I think [judiciary](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judiciary) should be the primary (because it is *slightly* more general) with [judge](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judge) being the synonym.

See "[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work):

> In some cases, tags that are subsets of other tags will also be considered synonyms, such as java-se for java.

Answer (score 1):

### These are not synonyms

A judge is an individual. The judiciary is the arm of government. It's like saying the President is the same as the Executive or a politician is the same as Parliament.

Comment: No, "judge" and "judiciary" are not synonyms in the dictionary sense. But we could reasonably decided that they should point to the same **search category**. That is, when someone searches for "judge" s/he should find both threads about individual judges, and about the group of judges  an institution, that is, the judiciary. That is what making these TAG-synonyms would do. It is not IMO essential, but would be reasonable, and the dictionary meaning alone would not IMO be a good argument against doing so.

Comment: A reasonable dictionary entry: Judge: A member of the Judicary presiding over a court in which cases are heard.  // Judicary: the entirety of the legal system.

Answer (score -1):

I agree. But if this is done, the tag wiki should be edited to make it clear that the tag includes questions about individual Judges or Justices as well s the judiciary as an institution.